# How to calculate and create new object value from two different arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

```
var array1 = [{issueCount: 16, failCount: 38, id: 1},
{issueCount: 15, failCount: 37, id: 2},
{issueCount: 15, failCount: 34, id: 3}];

var array2 = [{id: 1, totalAttempts: 57},
{id: 2, totalAttempts: 59},
{id: 3, totalAttempts: 67},
{id: 4, totalAttempts: 59}];
```

I have two arrays. From the above arrays, I need to calculate failure Percentage using the (array1. fail count/array2.totalAttempts) * 100 [id is common between two arrays]. And the final array wants in the below format.

```
outputArray = [{id: 1, issueCount: 16, failCount: 38, percentage: 66.66},
{id: 2, issueCount: 15, failCount: 37, percentage: 62.71},
{id: 3, issueCount: 15, failCount: 34, percentage: 50.74}];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: outputArray = [];

array1.forEach(function(dataItem1, idx) {
  var array2Items = array2[idx];
  var outputItems = {};
  if(dataItem1.id == array2Items.id){
    outputItems.id = dataItem1.id;
    outputItems.issueCount = dataItem1.issueCount;
    outputItems.failCount = dataItem1.failCount;
    outputItems.percentage = (dataItem1.failCount/array2Items.totalAttempts)*100;
    outputArray.push(outputItems);
  }
});

Comment: The above code is working fine, when I have array1 length and array2 length are same and array2 length > array1 length. But, when I have array1 length > array 2 length it is not working. what is code improvement should I need to add to achieve for all the scenario. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should really take the tour to learn how this site works. Both solutions provided will solve your problem even with diffrent array lengths. If you just write a comment to your own answer no one will see it

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a simple for loop.

Just check if the id exists in the second array, if so make your calculations.

```js
const array1 = [{issueCount: 16, failCount: 38, id: 1},
{issueCount: 15, failCount: 37, id: 2},
{issueCount: 15, failCount: 34, id: 3}];

const array2 = [{id: 1, totalAttempts: 57},
{id: 2, totalAttempts: 59},
{id: 3, totalAttempts: 67},
{id: 4, totalAttempts: 59}];

const outputArray = [];

array1.forEach(i1 => {
  const i2 = array2.find(i => i.id === i1.id);
  if(i2) {
    outputArray.push({
      id: i1.id, 
      issueCount: i1.issueCount, 
      failCount: i1.failCount,
      percentage: (i1.failCount / i2.totalAttempts) * 100
      }); 
  }
});
console.log(outputArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```js
const array1 = [{issueCount: 16, failCount: 38, id: 1},{issueCount: 15, failCount: 37, id: 2},{issueCount: 15, failCount: 34, id: 3}]
const array2 = [{id: 1, totalAttempts: 57},{id: 2, totalAttempts: 59},{id: 3, totalAttempts: 67},{id: 4, totalAttempts: 59}]

const mergedArrays = Object.values([...array1, ...array2].reduce((a, c) => (a[c.id] = { ...a[c.id], ...c }, a), {}))
const outputArray = mergedArrays
  .filter(o => o.issueCount && o.totalAttempts)
  .map(({ id, issueCount, failCount, percentage, totalAttempts }) => ({
    id, 
    issueCount, 
    failCount,
    percentage: Math.round(failCount / totalAttempts * 100 * 100) / 100
  }))
  
console.log(outputArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your posts. I have also find the solution below.

```
outputArray = []; 
    array1.forEach(function(dataItem1, idx) { 
        var array2Items = array2[idx]; 
        var outputItems = {}; 
        if (dataItem1 && array2Items){
        if(dataItem1.id == array2Items.id){ 
            outputItems.id = dataItem1.id; 
            outputItems.issueCount = dataItem1.issueCount; 
            outputItems.failCount = dataItem1.failCount; 
            outputItems.percentage = ((dataItem1.failCount/array2Items.totalAttempts)*100).toFixed(2); 
            outputArray.push(outputItems); 
        } 
        }
    });
    
    console.log(outputArray);
```

Comment: This apporach will work with your test data but is error prone.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I agree. The real-time scenario is different than this post. In the original code, I am using find() and other company-specific proprietary tools. So, it makes us not error-prone. Thank you